# Looping total not same in database

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Hello i have a script **looping php, and each loop 4 data/row then show ads**.

but i have a problem.. because in database i have data 123 row. 
but in show in php only  92 row/data :'(

**this is my script**

```
<?php 
include "connection.php";
$i=0; 
$data_school=mysql_query("select * from school");
while ($school=mysql_fetch_object($data_school)) 
{
    if($i%4==0)
    { 
    echo "<br/><a href='#'><img src='ads.jpg' alt=''></a><br/>";
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo $school->name_school"<br/>";
    }
$i++;
}
?>
```

when i run in browser, and ads show but school only show "**92 row/data**"

**if i remove script**

```
 if($i%4==0)
        { 
        echo "<br/><a href='#'><img src='ads.jpg' alt=''></a><br/>";
        }
```

then script be like this

```
<?php 
    include "connection.php";
    $i=0; 
    $data_school=mysql_query("select * from school");
    while ($school=mysql_fetch_object($data_school)) 
    {
            echo $school->name_school"<br/>";

    $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

this data show all **123 row/data**

help me, i want like this

school 1

school 2

school 3

school 4

#ads

school 5

school 6

school 7

school 8

#ads

Help me, Thank's

Comment: You're using an `if` statement. If this is the 4th (or 8th, or 12th) row, you print out the advert. If it's not, you print out the schoolname. Try removing the `else` part of your statement - you want to print out the schoolname every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$i=0;
$data_school=mysql_query("select * from school");
while ($school=mysql_fetch_object($data_school))
{
    if($i%4==0)
    {
        echo "<br/><a href='#'><img src='ads.jpg' alt=''></a><br/>";
    }
    echo $school->name_school . "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

You want to echo the school name every time

Also why aren't you getting errors on this:

```
echo $school->name_school"<br/>";
```

Comment: Thank's Nathan it's work..
but, how to, if data school have a statetement like this > 
http://pastebin.com/J3CWN4DB

Answer (score 1):

The if/else structure you're using makes it so that you don't echo every fourth entry. You want to echo `$school->name_school` each time regardless of whether or not `$i%4==0`. You want to do this:

```
<?php 
include "connection.php";
$i=0; 
$data_school=mysql_query("select * from school");
while ($school=mysql_fetch_object($data_school)) 
{
    if($i%4==0)
    { 
        echo "<br/><a href='#'><img src='ads.jpg' alt=''></a><br/>";
    }

        // This line will now display EACH time, not just when $i%4 != 0
        echo $school->name_school . '<br/>'; 

    $i++;
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: echo $school->name_school"<br/>"; will give errors ;)

Comment: @Gajelo That code from pastebin should work fine as you have it. Are you having a problem with it?